# Visual Studio Set file deployment path

Tags: visual-studio, file, deployment, compact-framework

I've got a .net compact framework project containing a lots of different files (DLLs, Images,...)

I need those files to be copied directly into the deployment folder on the device. As it is very confusing to have all those files within a project, i'd like to seperate them into various subfolders.

The problem is, that files within subfolders in the project are copied into subfolders on the device too.

Is it possible to put those files in subfolders within the project, and specify the deployment path, so they are copied to the "deployment-root-folder"?

Thanks!

---

### EDIT

Thanks, but the problem is not, how to publish the files in the right way, when using an installer. How do i get the files in the right directory when debugging?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds at least similar to web server-based applications on Windows CE, where I have a load of aspx, image, CSS, JS, CS etc files that I need deployed, but that I don't necessarily want cluttering up my debug project structure where it makes it difficult to find the CS files.

My solution was to create a separate project (I call it "Static Content" but the name's not important) that contains all of these deployment items and have it's output set to the same as the project I'm debugging.  Manually set a project dependency for the code app to depend on the static files app and that will force Studio to deploy it when you debug.

[image]

This allows you to at least collapse the 'static files' project to help keep the tree browsable.

Comment: That's a great tip, I was always annoyed you couldn't have finer control over where content files get deployed in my projects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy them into the directory structure you want used in your exe project.

In the deployment project, you simply mimic the patern you have established in your exe project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. Well, not easily at least.

You can specify the target root folder for each project when deploying/debugging, but Visual Studio offers no built-in support for individual file targets.

If you really want to achieve the result you're looking for, you could presumably write a utility to move the files around after the deployment and then fire the utility as a part of a post-build step. There may be side-effects to this, as you're moving outside of functionality provided by Visual Studio.